# Copying a 50gb mysql database to another server

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some ideas to copy over a 50gb mysql database, i am having a nightmare with it. For mysqldump to work properly i had to change the ssh session to not time out, then i used wget on the other server to download the sql dump.

Then, when i cam to import it like this:

```
mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u dbuser -p dbname < web.sql
```

I am now getting this cryptic error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'nohup: ignoring input






/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_S' at line 1
```

The original server doesn't use MariaDB, could that be the issue? I don't see how a dump from mysql itself wouldn't import.

Comment: I recommend to copy using raw data files copying with attaching them on the destination server by discard/import tablespace operations. Or use complete raw copying method like described in the replication solutions.

Comment: PS. Servers versions must match strictly !

Comment: Is the shell command "nohup" anywhere in  `web.sql`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's junk -- some sort of Linux error message or something -- in the first line of your `web.sql` file.

Assuming you're on a Linux or other UNIX-based system, look at the first few lines of the file with

```
head web.sql
```

Try this command line to load your file while deleting the first three lines. You might need to delete more or fewer lines depending on the junk in the file.

```bash
cat web.sql | sed 1,3d | mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u dbuser -p dbname
```

This pipes your file through the [sed stream editor](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) removing the first lines. It's handy in this case because ordinary text editors may have trouble with 50GiB files.

Comment: Yeh this is why i've not attempted to open it to look, it just won't work and chew up ram. I have exported it with--no-tablespaces to try and remove an error, hopefully that's it, if not will try your suggestion. I'll come back to you.

Comment: Ok so i tried it and the error has gone, however all i get now is MySql Server Has Gone Away!